# Linux bashscript with infinite loop stops working after some time

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script which is schedule to run every 1 minute in CRON. There is also an instance checker inside the script so that it won't execute the script more than once.
The script has an infinite loop which tries to check if a directory have any files. If there are files available it will send those files via CURL. There is a sleep for 1 sec after that it resumes the while infinite loop. Files continuously arrive in the folder every second.

Please see below code snippet.

The script works as expected for maybe 15-20 mins but after that it just doesn't detect any new files. I was wondering if there is something I should modify on my script below.

## Updated

```
        infinite_loop() {

                while true
                do
                        TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`



                        while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do

                                echo "File List ARR: $file"

     SEND_POST=`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=$file" URL_HERE`

                                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                                        echo "$TIMESTAMP - File successfully sent"


                                        mv $file $PROC/$file

                                else
                                        echo "$TIMESTAMP - Error sending file"
                                fi
unset file

                        done < <(find "${WORK}" -name "*.xml" -print0)



                echo `date` "sleeping..."
                sleep 1
                done

        }
```

## Update

This is the part where it will ensure that no more than 1 script is running

```
scriptChecker() {

searchString="ps -efl | grep "mysearchString" | grep -v \"grep\" | wc -l"

        if [ $searchString -le 1 ]; then
                echo "Run  script "
                infinite_loop
        else
                echo "Another script is running "
                exit 1
        fi
}
```

Managed to increase the time script will timeout from 15 mins to almost an hour. After that it will just freeze and not detect any files.
I think the file in when is causing some problems because it's repeatedly being looped gazillion times. I don't have a clue as to what happens in the background if the variable inside a loop is re-initialized or the memory being freed. But appreciate if anyone can provide a feedback. Thanks

Comment: If, as you say, it never exits, why do you start it once a minute? If you start it once a minute from `cron` and it runs forever, you will soon end up with a slew of fighting processes. I guess your instance checker isn't working.

Comment: Hi mark thanks for the feedback. The instance checker is working as expected whenever there is an existing process it will not execute the same script. However you are right scheduling it per minute doesn't make sense. We will set probably another schedule for it... but i think it's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try pasting your script into https://shellcheck.net

Comment: hi mark, i've provided an update. I think there is a problem with the variable file inside my while loop. I don't know what happens to $file if it's repeatedly assign a value... and i think this is what's causing it to just crash and timeout.

Comment: You are still failing to double quote variables, `mv "$file" "$PROC"`

Comment: But it's moving the files though... i could see it in the logs.

Comment: Can you clarify:fileName=`echo "$file" | cut -f9 -d/` and the value of PROC. Is PROC under $WORK ? Also, is it possible that an extra instance was launched, and the 2 instances are competing for work. This will be consistent with your description.

Comment: It will work, until a file with a space in its name comes along...

Comment: i've added the part where i check if there are scripts running with the same name...

Comment: Don't pipe the results of grep to wc and then compare the value.  Just do `if ... | grep -q ... ; then`